# Normalizar un Form cuando este está minimizado por un valor

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de realizar lo siguiente:

> > Al iniciar sesión, se carga un formulario que realiza una consulta a `SQL` sobre si hay o no un registro cargado. Sino hay un registro, se debe minimizar el `Form` pasado los **3(tres) segundos**. Para ello ejecuto un `Timer` y se minimiza.
> >
> > > Ahora, una vez minimizado el `Form` este debe volver a aparecer en pantalla de manera automática cuando hay registro nuevo.

¿Cómo puedo volver a normalizar el `Form` cuando este recibe un nuevo registro?

Apenas se abre el formulario, pregunto si el registro contiene o no n registros:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    int milliseconds;
    const int TIME_TO_MINIMIZE = 3000;
    const int TIME_TO_MAXIMIZE = 1000;

    public Providus_Mensajero(string usuario)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        usuarioString = usuario;
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        var datoString = conexionSQL.consultaLista(usuario);
        string dato = Convert.ToString(datoString);

        milliseconds = 0;

        //datos de la listaDatos
        for (int i = 0; i < datoString.Count; i++)
        {
            cantidad = datoString[0].cantidad;
            id = datoString[i].id;
            usuid = datoString[i].usuid;
        }
        lblPrueba.Text = cantidad;
        if(cantidad == null || cantidad.Equals("") || cantidad.Equals("0"))
        {
            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        milliseconds += 100;
        if (milliseconds >= TIME_TO_MINIMIZE)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            milliseconds = 0;
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        milliseconds += 100;
        if (milliseconds <= TIME_TO_MAXIMIZE)
        {
            milliseconds = 0;
        }
    }

    private void InputAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        milliseconds = 0;
    }
```

Una vez minimizado, el `timer` debe activarse y ejecutarse constantemente hasta que se reciba un nuevo registro y con lo cual debe volver a normalizarse el `Form`, para ello utilizo el evento `Rezise`:

```
    private void Providus_Mensajero_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
            timer.Start();

            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
            var respuestaDeConsulta = conexionSQL.consultaLista(usuarioString);
            string intento = "";
            if(respuestaDeConsulta.Count <= 0)
            {
                intento = "";
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < respuestaDeConsulta.Count; i++)
                {
                    intento = respuestaDeConsulta[0].cantidad;
                }
                lblPrueba.Text = "";
                lblPrueba.Text = intento;

                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                timer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero, no funciona ya que por más que a mi BD le ingrese un nuevo registro, no se me normaliza el `Form`, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

El proceso entra por el IF y luego termina el evento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si por ejemplo 20 usuarios a la vez agregan 1 registro con lo cual serían 20 registros nuevos en la base de datos. Se normaliza 1 vez y se minimiza. Y las 19 restantes esperan en cola para normalizarse una por una?

Comment: Sabes si al menos llega a ejecutarse Providus_Mensajero_Resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aca hay varios conceptos desordenados e incorrectos, asi que vayamos por partes.

> Al iniciar sesión, se carga un formulario que realiza una consulta a SQL sobre si hay o no un registro cargado. Sino hay un registro, se debe minimizar el Form pasado los 3(tres) segundos.

Eso esta en el constructor del formulario:

```
public Providus_Mensajero(string usuario)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    //Este for no tiene ningun sentido. id y usuid son variables, 
    //con lo cual tienen el ultimo valor solamente
    for (int i = 0; i < datoString.Count; i++)
    {
        cantidad = datoString[0].cantidad;
        id = datoString[i].id;
        usuid = datoString[i].usuid;
    }
    //capaz seria mejor String.IsNullOrEmpty, pero ese cero al final es muy raro
    if(cantidad == null || cantidad.Equals("") || cantidad.Equals("0"))
    {
        //donde definiste el timer? si esta definido en el form, para que haces todo esto?
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000 //si queres 3 segundos, pones 3000!!!!!!!
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

El timer que minimiza deberia ser asi:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sigue sin haber registros)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        //y aca prendemos el timer2 y apagamos este, no?
        timer1.stop();
        // Y suponiendo que configuraste el timer2 en el form como corresponde
        timer2.Interval = 1000;
        timer2.start(); 
    }
}
```

Ahora, tu evento timer2 debe hacer lo siguiente, que es todo lo que esta en el event rezize

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aca va tu comprobacion de registros;
    if (hay registros)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        timer2.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues no, algo debo haber hecho mal porque al modificar mi código en base al tuyo. Luego de insertar el registro, no se minimizó el form

Comment: donde decis que se tiene que minimizar al agregar un registro? eso no esta en tu pregunta, y no esta en mi codigo... el codigo es una idea de lo que tenes que hacer...

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo usaré como ejemplo y lo modificaré según sea necesario

Answer (score 1):

Intenta lo siguiente, activa el reloj2 cuando minimizas el form con el reloj1 en el Evento Tick, de la misma forma en que lo haces cuando detectas cantidades.

Y Si Quieres Que Aparezca Cuando Haya Nuevas Cantidades has de Hacer-le Que el Evento Timer2 Compruebe Nuevas Cantidades para detectar-lo de la forma en que lo detectas...

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
int milliseconds;
const int TIME_TO_MINIMIZE = 3000;
const int TIME_TO_MAXIMIZE = 1000;

public Providus_Mensajero(string usuario)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    usuarioString = usuario;
    ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
    var datoString = conexionSQL.consultaLista(usuario);
    //string dato = Convert.ToString(datoString);

    milliseconds = 0;
    cantidad = "";
      
    //datos de la listaDatos
    for (int i = 0; i < datoString.Count; i++)
    {
        cantidad = datoString[0].cantidad;
        id = datoString[i].id;
        usuid = datoString[i].usuid;
    }
    lblPrueba.Text = cantidad;
    if(cantidad == null || cantidad.Equals("") || cantidad.Equals("0") )
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliseconds += 100;
    if (milliseconds >= TIME_TO_MINIMIZE)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        milliseconds = 0;
        timer1.Enabled = False;
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliseconds += 100;
    if (milliseconds <= TIME_TO_MAXIMIZE)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        milliseconds = 0;
        timer2.Enabled = False;
    }
}

private void InputAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliseconds = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo que propongo es lo siguiente y es que crearía un único timer que es el que servirá para mantener 3 segundos visible el formulario. Para ello lo incializaria con un llamado al siguiente procedimiento:

```
private void InitializaTimer()
{
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 100;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    // Inicialmente parado
    timer.Stop();
    milliseconds = 0; 
}
```

En el evento Tick del timer nos aseguramos de detener el reloj si ya cumplió los 3 segundos:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliseconds += 100;
    if (milliseconds >= TIME_TO_MINIMIZE)
    {
       this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
       timer.Stop();  // detenemos el timer
       milliseconds = 0;
    }
}

public Providus_Mensajero(string usuario)
{
     ...

    if(cantidad == null || cantidad.Equals("") || cantidad.Equals("0"))
    {
        // Activamos el timer
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

El segundo timer lo veo innecesario, y *Providus_Mensajero_Resize* quedaría así:

```
private void Providus_Mensajero_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        //timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        //timer.Interval = 100;
        //timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
        //timer.Start();

        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        var respuestaDeConsulta = conexionSQL.consultaLista(usuarioString);
        string intento = "";
        if(respuestaDeConsulta.Count <= 0)
        {
            intento = "";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < respuestaDeConsulta.Count; i++)
            {
                intento = respuestaDeConsulta[0].cantidad;
            }
            lblPrueba.Text = "";
            lblPrueba.Text = intento;

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            //timer.Stop();

            // Como se ha reestablecido en FormWindowState.Normal porque
            // hay un registro nuevo, entonces activo el timer para que 
            // comience la cuenta de los 3 segundos antes de volver a
            // minimizar la ventana.
            timer.Start(); 
        }
    }
}
```